# call to method.invoke with variable number of arguments

Tags: java, reflection, variadic-functions

Having

```
public Object callRemote (String sRemoteInterface, String sMethod,
            Object... arguments);
```

I want to do something like:

```
method.invoke(
            instance, 
            arguments..., 
            sessionId
        );
```

So it works for methods with a variable number of arguments.

How can I do it?

[EDIT] Here is the actual code I am using right now. It works for 1 or 2 arguments, but it needs to be made generic for N arguments:

```
public Object callRemote (String sRemoteInterface, String sMethod,
            Object... arguments) throws Exception {

    Object instance;
    Method method;

    if (sRemoteInterface==null) {

        throw new Exception("Must specify a remote interface to locate.");

    }

    instance = this.locator.getRemoteReference(sRemoteInterface, this.sessionId);

    if (arguments.length == 2) {

        method = instance.getClass().getMethod(
            sMethod, 
            arguments[0].getClass(),
            arguments[1].getClass(),
            int.class
        );

        return method.invoke(
            instance, 
            arguments[0], 
            arguments[1], 
            sessionId
        );

    } else {

        method = instance.getClass().getMethod(
            sMethod, 
            arguments[0].getClass(), 
            int.class
        );

        return method.invoke(
            instance, 
            arguments[0], 
            sessionId
        );

    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried `method.invoke(instance, arguments[0], arguments[1], sessionId);` which worked when all the methods had two arguments. Now some of them have only one and others 2, so it's not working. Would a simple replacement for `method.invoke(instance, arguments, sessionId);` work for any number of arguments?

Comment: Could you post code example which will let us reproduce your problem? There can be many problems with reflection and varargs but explaining each one of them in answer would take very long time.

Comment: posted update with the whole method. I don't know if I am expressing it right, but what I want to do boils down to calling a method through `method.invoke` using the variable number of arguments `arguments`received on my varargs method `callRemote`.

Comment: Code you posted doesn't compile since I don't have rest of necessary fields. Please create [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it with following snippet. The idea is that you pass the varargs through (getMethod also has varargs). I omitted the code for instance creation.

```
int sessionId;

Object callRemote(Object instance, String sMethod, Object... arguments) throws Exception {
    Class<?>[] argumentTypes = createArgumentTypes(arguments);
    Method method = instance.getClass().getMethod(sMethod, argumentTypes );
    Object[] argumentsWithSession = createArguments(arguments);
    return method.invoke(instance, argumentsWithSession);
}

Object[] createArguments(Object[] arguments) {
    Object[] args = new Object[arguments.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(arguments, 0, args, 0, arguments.length);
    args[arguments.length] = sessionId;
    return args;
}

Class<?>[] createArgumentTypes(Object[] arguments) {
    Class[] types = new Class[arguments.length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        types[i] = arguments[i].getClass();
    }
    types[arguments.length] = int.class;
    return types;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. With the minor correction that you missed an index (it should be `arguments[i].getClass()`), that's the idea and the implementation. Thank you!